# ThreadExecutor forcing execution of Thread in infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded server application. One of the Runnables uses an infinite loop to keep checking for connections. This is done using `socket = serverSocket.accept()` , which is a blocking call.

When I shutdown my server I want to to stop all of my threads from executing.
I tried `threadExecutor.shutdown()` and `threadExecutor.shutdownNow()`.

None of those functions seem to kill the thread I mentioned above.

Could you guys possibly help me out here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to set a `timeout` and use it to periodically check if termination is requested. if so - break the infinite loop - http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29

Comment: Note that [`ExecutorService#shutdown`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) means that pending tasks should be executed and no new tasks will be accepted.

Comment: do not submit blocking tasks to a thread pool. Run them on separate threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I shutdown my server I want to to stop all of my threads from executing.

When a thread is blocked in `serverSocket.accept()`, the only way to stop it is to close the `serverSocket` out from under it.  The accept call will then throw a `IOException` which can be caught and the thread should then quit.

If you also need to stop the client handler threads then you will need to have them listen for thread interrupts.  Interrupting a thread does not stop it from running but it will set the interrupt flag on the thread and will cause any methods that throw `InterruptedException` to throw.  To interrupt the threads in the `ExecutorService` you would call `threadExecutor.shutdownNow()`.  However, this does not interrupt the `accept()` call.

Typically in a thread handle loop we do something like:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: this looks more like a hack to me

Comment: Without using NIO code, that's the only way to do it from the server side @SvetlinZarev.  It's a very typical pattern.

Comment: @Gray I tried closing the serverSocket and catching a SocketException. Which works, thanks! This might be a different question on its own, but how come my client can still communicate with my server when I close my serverSocket?

Comment: Because the client is working on an accepted socket @Noiseloop.  Once you get a connection you can close the server socket and it doesn't affect any clients already connected.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution: during server shutdown connect to the socket and write a *STOP* message. Have the thread `break` out of its infinite loop as a result of receiving this *STOP* message.

Comment: but this requires a message from client

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, it requires a message but not from a client. The server can connect to its own listening TCP/IP socket, just _like_ a client.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but accepting this connection will result in a new `Socket` being created as a result of the `accept()` call, and most probably it will be handled in a separate thread - in the mean time the `ServerSocket` will block again waiting to accept the next connection

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, it does not have to be handled in a separate thread. Even it was passed to another `Runnable` it would exit immediately as it has nothing to do. The OP can decide how to handle this. This answer provides a very simple mechanism for waking the server thread immediately. The OP could set a flag to indicate shutdown is required before calling `accept()` or have the server thread peek at the incoming data to detect a _STOP_ message.